# Is there any way to calc width on tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there a way to make width using calc() on tailwind?

```
width: calc(100% - 40px)
```

without making separate values on the configs file each time?

Answer (score 18):

If you only need this value once, and the Tailwind version you're using supports [Just-in-Time mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode), I would suggest you to use the [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support) feature.

```
<div class="w-[calc(100%-40px)]"></div>
```

Depending on your use case, there might be better solutions.